# How do I print the boolean value?

Tags: swift, var, boolean-expression

Okay, so I'm currently trying to write the code for a very inaccurate stoplight--one that is only meant to help me understand what I've learned, but I can't seem to figure it out! In my code, at the very end, I say `print("Green Light!")` after setting up a few variables, but I would like to indicate what the computer should do instead of flat out saying "print this phrase," if that makes sense... not sure it does.

How would I write this if I wanted to simply print the Boolean value of greenLight without saying `print("Green Light!")`?

I'm very much a beginner and I might be asking the wrong question--I know that, but I'm hoping someone can help!

Something tells me I haven't learned enough to do this, yet, but I really wanna know how this works.

This is what I've written so far. It runs, but I would like to change it so all I have to say is `print(greenLight)` or `print(Bool)`.

When I try putting in print(greenLight), it returns an error:

Output:
Review.swift:14:7: error: variable 'greenLight' used before being initialized
print(greenLight)
^
Review.swift:4:5: note: variable defined here
var greenLight: Bool
^

```
var carAtRightIntersection = false
var carAtLeftIntersection = false
var carStraightAhead = true
var greenLight: Bool

if !(carAtRightIntersection && carAtLeftIntersection) && carStraightAhead {
  greenLight = true
}

if carAtRightIntersection && carAtLeftIntersection && !(carStraightAhead) {
  greenLight = false
}

print("Green light!")
```

Edit: I consulted a few coding friends, and they provided a very good solution! Provided here:

```
var carAtRightIntersection = false
var carAtLeftIntersection = false
var carStraightAhead = true
var colorOfLight: String = "Red"

if !(carAtRightIntersection && carAtLeftIntersection) && carStraightAhead {
  colorOfLight = "Green"
}
/*
if carAtRightIntersection && carAtLeftIntersection && !(carStraightAhead) {
  greenLight = false 
}
*/

print(colorOfLight + " light :)")
```

Comment: Yes. I'll update my post with the error I got.

Comment: Your problem is that if neither of your if statements are true then `greenLight` would be uninitialized (won't have had a value set) and the compiler will prevent you from accessing it.

Comment: Instead of `var greenLight: Bool` use `var greenLight: Bool = false`

Comment: Check out https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: Oh, I think I understand, dan. Thank you for your help. I'll try rewriting it and report back

Comment: Thank you, jnpdx. That fixed my problem! That's the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to print the actual phrases, You could use a switch case statement

```
switch greenLight{

case true:
    print("Green Light!")

case false:
    print("Red Light!")

default:
    print("Yellow Light!")
}
```

After the first block executes

Comment: ***Default will never be executed***

Comment: In this specific example it will not, but I wanted to show the capability of the switch-case statement.